# Button isn't appearing

Tags: c++, fltk

I am supposed to draw window that has a light bulb and have a button that turns it on ( white) and off( black). Here is the full objective:Write a program to display a window with a circle representing a light bulb and a button labelled "ON/OFF".  The light bulb starts off black, i.e., off.  When the button is clicked, the light bulb turns on, i.e., white.  When the button is clicked again, the light goes off, and so on.
But for some reason, the circle doesn't appear in the window Here is my code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_5.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "Point.h"

struct Lines_window : Graph_lib::Window {
    Lines_window(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title);

    Circle light_bulb{Point{400,400},150};

private:
    Button on;

    bool button_pushed;

    static void cb_on1(Address, Address);       // callback for next_button

    void on1();  // action to be done when next_button is pressed
};

Lines_window::Lines_window(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title)
:Window{xy,w,h,title},
on{Point{x_max()-100,0}, 70, 20, "ON/OFF",cb_on1},
button_pushed{false}
{
    attach(on);
}


void Lines_window::cb_on1(Address, Address pw)
// call Simple_window::next() for the window located at pw
{
    reference_to<Lines_window>(pw).on1();
}

void Lines_window::on1(){

    if (button_pushed)
    {
        light_bulb.set_fill_color(Color::white);
        button_pushed = false;
        redraw();
    }
    else
    {
        light_bulb.set_fill_color(Color::black);
        button_pushed = true;
        redraw();
    }
    redraw();
}

int main ()
{
    try{
        Lines_window win {Point{100,100},800,800,"Light Bulb"};
        return gui_main();

    }
    catch (exception& e){ //catches range errors and run_time_errors
        cerr << "error: "<< e.what() <<'\n';
        return 1;
    }
    catch (...){ //catch any exception
        cerr <<"Exception: something went wrong \n";
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no "button" in C++ and you must use some external or OS library for that

Comment: Button is not an FLTK function - you need to look into your library to see how it has been implemented.  It is probably a wrapper around Fl_Button.